# Kicking off a workflow with an event handler on an anonymously submitted list item

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, event-handlers

I have a form that allows anonymous users to submit parking requests. I have an approval workflow set up but it won't start because anonymous users don't have permission to do so. Would an event handler make it possible to run the workflow on ItemAdded regardless of who adds it?

Comment: Any solution to this? care to share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this currently a Visual Studio workflow, or a SP Designer workflow?
Also, is this SP2010 or 2007?
If it's SPD, and you're on 2010, you can now wrap your actions in an Elevated block directly in Designer.

If you're already in Visual Studio, you can follow Ybbest's suggestion and run the code with Elevated Privileges.

Comment: It's actually a Nintex workflow. We're using 2010. The problem with that solution is that when the workflow is set to automatically start when an item is added and an anonymous user adds an item, the workflow starts but it doesn't run. It can then be terminated and run by an authenticated user. I've tried the run with elevated privilege in SPD and the same thing happens.

Comment: Another option (made easy with Nintex) would be to have the workflow run on a schedule on any item in the list that's not approved.

Comment: I've noticed the nintex worflows don't start when the user is the farm admin, try impersonating with another user. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap up you code in a elevated privileges code block in your event handler.It is similar to impersonation used in asp.net.You can have a look at the following example.
http://code-journey.com/2010/run-code-with-elevated-privileges-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

here is a method that will solve this issue for you

```
public void StartWorkflow(SPWorkflowManager manager, string eventData, SPListItem listItem, SPWorkflowAssociation workflow)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWorkflowCollection workflows = manager.GetItemActiveWorkflows(listItem);
                if (workflows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                manager.StartWorkflow(listItem, workflow, string.Empty, true);
            });
        }
```